# parsing JSON with a decodable?

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I have a `JSON` file:

```
{
"name": "Jens",
"time": "11.45",
"date": "2018:04:17",
"differentTimestamps":[""]
"aWholeLotOfnames":{
   "name1": "Karl"
   "name2": "pär"
 }
```

How to parse above `JSON` ? I have checked this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY3bTxgxWss. One text tutorial to but i don't get how to make a variable that can take a

```
"nameOfVar"{}
```

If it's not a dictionary. The tutorial are using a var `nameOfVar`: [what should be here in this case] for one that nearly looks like it. The thing is though that theirs are starting with a [{ and ends with a }] while mine only starts with a {? i don't know how to solve this?

Comment: ` [{}]` That's an array of dictionary. That's all. You need to adapt your parsing if it's a "String/Int", or a Dict or an Array at each level.

Comment: This looks like an invalid JSON, duplicate keys are not allowed within a JSON

Comment: Please give a more realistic example. Dictionaries have unique keys and the value in the last dictionary is missing.

Comment: it's a example code it's different variable names it's just a example for how the JSON looks like and what i do not understand is how to create a dictionary decodable because if you place a dictionary in your class you get class not compatible with Decodable

Comment: made it more realistic now then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating corresponding Swift data types for JSON is very easy.

- A dictionary `{}` can be decoded into a class / struct where the keys become properties / members.
- An array `[]` can be decoded into an array of the given (decodable) type.
- Any value in double quotes is `String` even `"12"` or `"false"`.
- Numeric floating point values are `Double`, integer values are `Int` and `true / false` is `Bool`
- `null` is `nil`

---

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "name": "Jens",
    "time": "11.45",
    "date": "2018:04:17",
    "differentTimestamps":[""],
    "aWholeLotOfnames":{
        "name1": "Karl",
        "name2": "pär"
    }
}
"""

struct Item: Decodable {
    let name, time, date: String
    let differentTimestamps: [String]
    let aWholeLotOfnames: AWholeLotOfnames
}

struct AWholeLotOfnames : Decodable {
    let name1, name2 : String
}
```

---

```
let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Item.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: the second i add a class into the struct it gives me that the struct does not conform to protocol decodable?